# Get rid of the padding at the beginning and end of navbar so all content fits in one line

Tags: html, css

My navbar contents are displaying in two lines i want them to display in one line and get rid of the padding the beginning and end of navbar but i cant seem to identify the problem. any help would be appreciated,

```
 * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none
    }
    body {
        background: #555;
    }
    header {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        background: #333;
    }
    .logo {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 123;
        padding: 10px;
        font: 18px verdana;
        color: #6DDB07;
        float: left;
        width: 15%
    }
    .logo a {
        color: #6DDB07;
    }
    nav {
        position: relative;
        width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #cssmenu,
    #cssmenu ul,
    #cssmenu ul li,
    #cssmenu ul li a,
    #cssmenu #head-mobile {
        border: 0;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 1;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box
    }
    #cssmenu:after,
    #cssmenu > ul:after {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0
    }
    #cssmenu #head-mobile {
        display: none
    }
    #cssmenu {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background: #333
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li {
        float: left
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
        padding: 17px;
        font-size: 12px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ddd;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu ul li.active a {
        color: #fff
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li:hover,
    #cssmenu ul li.active:hover,
    #cssmenu ul li.active,
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub.active:hover {
        background: #448D00!important;
        -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: background .3s ease;
        transition: background .3s ease;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
        padding-right: 30px
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 22px;
        right: 11px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 2px;
        display: block;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 19px;
        right: 14px;
        display: block;
        width: 2px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #ddd;
        content: '';
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
        top: 23px;
        height: 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: -9999px
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
        height: 0;
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        background: #333;
        transition: all .25s ease
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover {} #cssmenu li:hover > ul {
        left: auto
    }
    #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
        height: 35px
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul {
        margin-left: 100%;
        top: 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
        padding: 11px 15px;
        width: 170px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ddd;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
        border-bottom: 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
        color: #fff
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 16px;
        right: 11px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 2px;
        display: block;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 13px;
        right: 14px;
        display: block;
        width: 2px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #ddd;
        content: '';
        -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
        top: 17px;
        height: 0
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover,
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover {
        background: #363636;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a {
        border-left: 1px solid #333
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,
    #cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a {
        border-top: 1px solid #333
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
        .logo {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 46px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 0 0 0;
            float: none
        }
        .logo2 {
            display: none
        }
        nav {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #cssmenu {
            width: 100%
        }
        #cssmenu ul {
            width: 100%;
            display: none
        }
        #cssmenu ul li {
            width: 100%;
            border-top: 1px solid #444
        }
        #cssmenu ul li:hover {
            background: #363636;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li,
        #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
            height: auto
        }
        #cssmenu ul li a,
        #cssmenu ul ul li a {
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 0
        }
        #cssmenu > ul > li {
            float: none
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li a {
            padding-left: 25px
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li {
            background: #333!important;
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
            background: #363636!important
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
            padding-left: 35px
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li a {
            color: #ddd;
            background: none
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
        #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
            color: #fff
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul,
        #cssmenu ul ul ul {
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: left
        }
        #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
        #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
        #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
        #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before 
        {
            display: none
        }
        #cssmenu #head-mobile {
            display: block;
            padding: 23px;
            color: #ddd;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: 700
        }
        .button {
            width: 55px;
            height: 46px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 12399994;
        }
        .button:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 22px;
            right: 20px;
            display: block;
            height: 4px;
            width: 20px;
            border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
            content: ''
        }
        .button:before {
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
            transition: all .3s ease;
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            right: 20px;
            display: block;
            height: 2px;
            width: 20px;
            background: #ddd;
            content: ''
        }
        .button.menu-opened:after {
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
            transition: all .3s ease;
            top: 23px;
            border: 0;
            height: 2px;
            width: 19px;
            background: #fff;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg)
        }
        .button.menu-opened:before {
            top: 23px;
            background: #fff;
            width: 19px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg)
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            display: block;
            border-left: 1px solid #444;
            height: 46px;
            width: 46px;
            cursor: pointer
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
            background: #262626
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
            height: 34px;
            width: 34px
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
            position: absolute;
            top: 22px;
            right: 19px;
            width: 8px;
            height: 2px;
            display: block;
            background: #ddd;
            content: ''
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
            top: 15px;
            right: 13px
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
            background: #fff
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 19px;
            right: 22px;
            display: block;
            width: 2px;
            height: 8px;
            background: #ddd;
            content: ''
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
            top: 12px;
            right: 16px
        }
        #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
            display: none
        }
        #cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a {
            border-left: none
        }
        #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,
        #cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a {
            border-top: none
}
```

following is the html of my code. my goal is to bring all the content in one centered navbar but i keep messing it up. can anyone help with what i am doing wrong. i would very much appreciate it.

```
<nav id='cssmenu'>
<div class="logo"><a href="#">something </a></div>
<div id="head-mobile"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>something</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>something</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">something</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">something</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">something</a>
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li ><a href="#">something</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">something</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">something</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<li><a href="#">something</a></li>

</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `contents are displaying in two lines`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my investigation there are some optimizations you can do to enhance the layout performance of your navbar.

- Update the width of the nav: `nav {width: 100%;}`
- Dont really understand why the logo has width:15%? Update to `.logo {width: auto;}`
- Align the nav-list to the right: `#cssmenu > ul {float:right;}`
- Align the items on second level to the left: `#cssmenu ul ul a {text-align: left;}`

Additionally if you want the logo in the center for mobile add this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .logo {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

Regarding your responsive styles I dont add the complete snippet here, rather link to this jsfiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/kv6a7hud/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> nav {
>          position: relative;
>          width: 100%;
>          margin: 0 auto;
>   }

Change width to 100% instead of 980px